# How can I access a public static variable from a different class in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am unable to access a public static boolean from a different class, eg. I have a boolean `isFull` in my `StudyjiosListviewScreen` class as shown:

```
class StudyjiosListviewScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _StudyjiosListviewScreenState createState() => _StudyjiosListviewScreenState();
}

class _StudyjiosListviewScreenState extends State<StudyjiosListviewScreen> {
  static bool isFull = false;
 ...
```

I want to use this boolean `isFull` in another class `JoinStudyjio`.
I created an instance of the `StudyjiosListviewScreen` class in the `JoinStudyjio` class like this:

```
StudyjiosListviewScreen listviewScreen = StudyjiosListviewScreen();
```

But when I try to use the boolean `isFull` like this:

```
if (listviewScreen.isFull) {

...
```

I get an error. I have already imported the file for the `StudyjiosListviewScreen` class inside the file for the `JoinStudyjio` class.

Comment: If you have a variable you want to share between classes, it would make more sense for you to pass down that value and possibly methods to modify it, down to the two classes you mentioned, from a parent class or somewhere else in your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `StudyjiosListviewScreen` and `_StudyjiosListviewScreenState` are 2 different classes.

The static variable `isFull` which you are trying to access is of the later one and you are trying to access it by creating an instance of the first one. If it had been a static variable of the class `StudyjiosListviewScreen`, you could have accessed it without even creating an instance of that class like this `StudyjiosListviewScreen.isFull`

Comment: I've tried using `StudyjiosListviewScreen.isFull` but it does not work either.

Comment: like I mentioned, that would be possible only if `isFull` was a static variable of class `StudyjiosListviewScreen`. Not a variable of this `_StudyjiosListviewScreenState` class.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your issue correctly, and following the suggestion I made in my comment, here is a code example of sharing a variable and a method to change it's value, down to two classes from a parent class:

```
class VariableSharing62951032 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _VariableSharing62951032State createState() => _VariableSharing62951032State();
}

class _VariableSharing62951032State extends State<VariableSharing62951032> {
  bool isFull = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        ClassA62951032(isFull: isFull, swapIsFull: swapIsFull,),
        ClassB62951032(isFull: isFull, swapIsFull: swapIsFull,),
      ],
    );
  }

  void swapIsFull(){
    setState(() {
      isFull = !isFull;
    });
  }
}

class ClassA62951032 extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool isFull;
  final Function swapIsFull;

  ClassA62951032({
    this.isFull,
    this.swapIsFull
  });

  @override
  _ClassA62951032State createState() => _ClassA62951032State();
}

class _ClassA62951032State extends State<ClassA62951032> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('Class A'),
        Text(widget.isFull.toString()),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Swap isFull'),
          onPressed: () => widget.swapIsFull(),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class ClassB62951032 extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool isFull;
  final Function swapIsFull;

  ClassB62951032({
    this.isFull,
    this.swapIsFull
  });

  @override
  _ClassB62951032State createState() => _ClassB62951032State();
}

class _ClassB62951032State extends State<ClassB62951032> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('Class B'),
        Text(widget.isFull.toString()),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Swap isFull'),
          onPressed: () => widget.swapIsFull(),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sharing variables and methods between classes it's a huge deal in Flutter.

First of all, you are passing it in the wrong way. That variable is saved in your state widget, which **is defined as private**.
So, or you define it as public and than you pass a key associated with your state, or you change complitelly approach. I don't like passing keys and it is not good for production, so I will give you a better example using providers:

add provider library to your pubspec.yaml:

```
provider: ^4.3.1 // Or latest version
```

Create a class where you can save that value:

```
class valuesHelper {

  //In this class we are storing global, dynamic values


  bool _isSeen;

  valuesHelper() {
    this._isSeen = false;
  }

  void setValue(bool value) {
    this._isSeen = value;
  }
  
  bool getValue(){
    return this._isSeen;
  }
}
```

Now wrap your main with the provider and pass the valuesHelper();

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider(
      create: (_) => valuesHelper(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now call the Provider.of(context) wherever you want.

```
//Somwhere in your code when you have access to context:
ValueHelper helper = Provider.of<valueHelper>(context);

helper.setValue(true);



//Somwhereelse in your code when you have access to context:
ValueHelper helper = Provider.of<valueHelper>(context);

bool theValueIWant = helper.getValue();
```

If you have asynchronous stuff and huge state managment Blocs are even better and fancier, but for this kind of things Providers are more than enough.